# Akka http client - URI encoding

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to invoke a Rest API using akka http client using below code.

```
            val httpRequest = HttpRequest(
              method  = HttpMethods.GET,


          uri ="https://example.com/customers/~/profiles/dj2bQryHPCj4IVrc48xTPD%2Bhswk%2FqNWx%2BLuUA0G2T6GLnyBVD6wC231IjgDBYJnt/preferences",

              headers = List(Accept(MediaRange(MediaTypes.`application/json`.withParams(Map("v" → "3")))),
                RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;v=3"),
                RawHeader("Api-Key", "XYZ")
              )
            )
```

Http().singleRequest(httpRequest, GatewayHelper.connectionContext)

Before the call goes out, when i check the httprequest.uri (through debugger), there is a partial uri decoding that is happening (%2B changed to +) 
dj2bQryHPCj4IVrc48xTPD+hswk%2FqNWx+LuUA0G2T6GLnyBVD6wC231IjgDBYJnt

Because of this the API is returning an error. Is there option where we can make akka not tamper with the URI?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but `Spray` and `akka-http` have some configuration options to modify the strictness of the URIs.

Take a look to this: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/configuration.html#akka-http

The following parameter

> ## Sets the strictness mode for parsing request target URIs.
>
> ```
> # The following values are defined:
> #
> # `strict`: RFC3986-compliant URIs are required,
> #     a 400 response is triggered on violations
> #
> # `relaxed`: all visible 7-Bit ASCII chars are allowed
> #
> uri-parsing-mode = strict
> ```

You might want to change it to `relaxed` and test again.

Comment: I tried but that didnt help either.                                                                     uri = Uri.apply("https://example.com/customers/~/profiles/dj2bQryHPCj4IVrc48xTPD%2Bhswk%2FqNWx%2BLuUA0G2T6GLnyBVD6wC231IjgDBYJnt/preferences", Uri.ParsingMode.Relaxed) ,